# subdomain redirection using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect the url  http://testing.domain.com/ to http://testing.domain.com/admin/index.php

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to secure your home page.   Put this php code in your index.php.

```
header("Location: http://testing.domain.com/admin/index.php")  
exit;
```

If you got everything in admin folder, then you can use this one

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on                   
RewriteCond $1 !^(admin)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ admin/index.php [L]
```

Comment: It is not a good sultion, i think..Can i have the solution with htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Put the following into your `.htaccess` file

```
Redirect 301 http://testing.domain.com/ http://testing.domain.com/admin/index.php
```

Comment: Also, look up what the various 3xx (redirect) HTTP status codes mean. They are not necessarily interchangable.

Comment: +1 on what @MichaelKjörling said, you have to be careful with different permanent and temporary redirects.

Comment: where i have to put htacces ,in root folder or testing folder?

Comment: In the root folder, make sure it is named `.htaccess`

Comment: It is not working yet..Actually subdomain pages and folders is belongs to testing folder under root

Comment: @user634188 Sorry I don't understand can you re-phrase that?

Comment: i mean the file structure is like root->subdomainfolder->subdomainfiles

Comment: It should be in the subdomain folder then :)

Comment: So Is it need to create new htaccess file to subdomain folder?

Comment: Yes, you create the .htaccess file in the subdomain folder

Comment: Hi Myles Gray...Its not working ..i think ,htacces file is not workig properly , there is no response ..How to check whether the htacces is woking or not?

Comment: Check the steps detailed here: http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/web-redirection.shtml